# How to block packets whoes dst or src ip is not in a subnet?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I need to block some packets in ppp0, and the target ip or source ip of packets are not in

172.17.0.1/24, how to add rules in Iptables? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure if this is what you really want but this is what you are describing:

```
iptables -N ppp0traffic
iptables -A ppp0traffic -s 172.17.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A ppp0traffic -d 172.17.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A ppp0traffic -j DROP

iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -j ppp0traffic
iptables -A FORWARD -o ppp0 -j ppp0traffic
```

Comment: Equivalently, `! -s 172.17.0.0/24 ! -d 172.17.0.0/24 -j DROP`, but anyhow, that implements **and** while OP's question (as I read it) asks for **or** …

Answer (score 0):

That would have been -A INPUT too.

But if you do not have a route to 172.17.0.0/24 (check with `ip route show table all`), then these packets get automatically dropped; no need for rules.